# Particles rotation animation

Tags: animation, particles, random

Do you have any idea why can't I animate the particle orientation? )
Well, it's a distant forest. I need those trees to sway a little, but chaotically.
When i change "Random orientation" by mouse, they sway.
But when i create keyframes there is no movement.
I tried Noise modification in Graph editor. It doen's work too. Strange!
I don't remeber such problems. Usually anything you can activate[image] works properly.

Emmiter is a plane with transforms applied (just Scale).
If i use Velocity/Hair as an Axis orientation all trees lean forward about 45 degrees.

Comment: By default, the hair is initialized on the first frame and keeps its settings. To check each frame for new settings, you have to enable the _Regrow_ option at the top. But make sure _Hair Dynamics_ are disabled (like in your screenshot). Otherwise Blender will try to simulate the hair with things like gravity and wind etc. and ignore the keyframed animation (but simulation won't work either if _Regrow_ is checked, because the hair gets initialized on each frame).

Comment: Thanx very much! Regrow. Exactly! Forgot to try it! ;)